# Why do I have to use an anonymous function instead of passing an additional argument to `setTimeout`?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, settimeout

I want to stop this `requestAnimationFrame` after 1 second:

```js
rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

So I use `setTimeout`.

When I wrap the `cancelAnimationFrame(rAF)` in an arrow function, it works fine:

```js
setTimeout(() => cancelAnimationFrame(rAF), 1000);
```

But, when I use `cancelAnimationFrame` as the function itself and pass `rAF` as the third argument to `setTimeout`, it doesn’t work:

```js
setTimeout(cancelAnimationFrame, 1000, rAF);
```

I thought that I didn’t know the exact syntax for `setTimeout` at first. But, I think the syntax isn’t wrong as this code works fine:

```js
setTimeout(alert, 1000, "Hello");
```

Why doesn’t it work?

Comment: Well, `"Hello"` isn’t a variable that changes every frame.

Comment: The arrow function will use the "latest version" of `rAf`, whereas the non-arrow function will use `rAf` when you called the `setTimeout()` method

Comment: @NickParsons Could you explain it in more detail? Is it because the non-arrow function is use the parameters' values when calling the `setTimeout()`, whereas the arrow function uses them when executed after the timer is over?

Comment: @User9728 yes, the arrow function will only be invoked after ~1000ms, and by that time, your `rAf` would refer to the newest `rAf` (you haven't shown it here, but I'm assuming your calling `rAf = requestAnimationFrame(draw)` inside of the `draw` function - creating [mre] would help clarify this). With the non-arrow function, you're canceling the `rAf` that is set at the time the line `setTimeout()` is executed (and not the one that is set after the ~1000ms)

Comment: Besides the explanation that other users already provided, there is not really any good reason to use the variadic version of `setTimeout`. It has been kept for compatibility reasons, but I'd consider it a bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the moment in time at which `rAF` is evaluated.

### Explanation

Presumably, your code looks something like this:

```js
let rAF;
const draw = () => {
    // Do some work.
    
    rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };

rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

When you do this:

```js
setTimeout(cancelAnimationFrame, 1000, rAF);
```

you pass three values to `setTimeout`: a function, a number, and another number.
When this statement is executed the [call is evaluated](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation), meaning that first, the `setTimeout` identifier is resolved to a function reference.
Second, the three arguments are evaluated: the `cancelAnimationFrame` identifier is resolved to a function reference, then the number literal is a number primitive, then the `rAF` identifier is resolved to another number primitive.
Then, the [call is performed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-call).

That’s all that `setTimeout` sees.
In JavaScript, you cannot pass a reference to a number, like you can in C, for example.

Let’s assume `rAF` is initially `1`.
Over the course of one second, `rAF` has been repeatedly incremented and eventually reaches the value `61` or so.

Since you register the `setTimeout` at the start, the statement

```js
setTimeout(cancelAnimationFrame, 1000, rAF);
```

is equivalent to

```js
setTimeout(cancelAnimationFrame, 1000, 1);
```

However, the statement

```js
setTimeout(() => cancelAnimationFrame(rAF), 1000);
```

is *not* equivalent to

```js
setTimeout(() => cancelAnimationFrame(1), 1000);
```

The function bodies are only evaluated when they are called.
This means, JS *doesn’t* “peek inside the functions” and attempt to evaluate variables.
That statement essentially means *“call some function with some other function and the number 1000 as arguments”*.

When the one second is over and it’s time to cancel the animation frame, `setTimeout` executes its callback.
If the callback is `() => cancelAnimationFrame(rAF)`, then it’s executed, so the function body is evaluated: `cancelAnimationFrame(rAF)` is equivalent to `cancelAnimationFrame(61)`.

However, in the non-working case, `cancelAnimationFrame` stays the same, the argument `1` (equivalent to `rAF` at the time `setTimeout` was originally called) stays the same.
You can’t cancel frame 1 when you’re already at frame 61.

And `setTimeout(alert, 1000, "Hello");` works, of course, because `"Hello"` is static, is only evaluated once, never changes.

### Related

Here’s a more general situation where this behavior can be examined:

```js
let greeting = "Hello";
const greet = (theGreeting) => console.log(`${theGreeting}, world!`);
const boundGreeting = greet.bind(null, greeting);

greeting = "Goodbye";

boundGreeting(); // Logs "Hello, world!".
greet(greeting); // Logs "Goodbye, world!".
```

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) passes the 2nd parameter (`greeting`) as the 1st argument to `greet` (ignore the `null`).
This is much like using `setTimeout(greet, 0, greeting);`, except this is unrelated to timeouts and we call (the bound) `greet` ourselves.

You *could* pass something like a reference, i.e. an object, to make it work, if you had a function that also accepts an object:

```js
const timing = {
    rAF: null
  },
  cancelTiming = ({ rAF }) => cancelAnimationFrame(rAF),
  draw = () => {
    // Do some work.
    
    timing.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };

timing.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
setTimeout(cancelTiming, 1000, timing);
```

This works because when passing `timing`, the value being passed is a reference.
Mutating it, e.g. by updating the `rAF` property, is visible everywhere where this reference is visible.
But this makes programming quite cumbersome.

This is tangentially related to [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/4642212).

### Alternative

There’s an alternative to using `setTimeout`.
When [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) calls its callback function, it passes a [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp), similar to what [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) returns.
So you could make the check in your `draw` function:

```js
const timeoutTimestamp = performance.now() + 1000,
  draw = (now) => {
    // Do some work.
    
    if(now < timeoutTimestamp){
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
  };

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Related: [Stop requestAnimationFrame after a couple of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41330963/4642212).